# one div inside another appears while hovering - z-index not working

Tags: html, css, z-index

Here is my jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/6XdcY/4/.
I have the DIV which appears while hovering another DIV.

In containing div there is  with display: block and 100% width and height.
This `<A>` interferes the div which should appear while hovering.

```
<div id='language'>
    <a class='language' href='en'></a>
    <a class='delete' href='' ></a>
</div>
```

```css
#language {
    width: 172px;
    height: 218px;
    opacity: 0.85;
    margin: 2px;
    z-index: 1;
    float: left;
}


#language a.language {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    z-index: 2;
}


#language:hover {
    width: 172px;
    height: 218px;
    opacity: 1; 
    cursor: pointer;
}


#language:hover .delete{
    display: block;
}


.delete {
    display: none;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;   
    background: #fff url(http://tyche.ge/palabra/images/delete_language.png);
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    border-left: 1px solid #88bde4;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #88bde4;
    margin-right: 1px;
    margin-top: 1px;
    top: 1;
    right: 1;
    float: right;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

The delete button should be inside the containing div.
You'll understand better with jsfiddle.
Thanks in advance

Comment: I tried to add POSITION, but failed..

Comment: For starters, multiple IDs with the same name isn't allowed. Identify them with a [class instead](http://jsfiddle.net/6XdcY/5/)

Comment: multiple IDs with the same name ? :)

Comment: You have 2 divs with `id="language"`, id is a unique identifier, so you [can't use the same one twice](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_id.asp). If you want 2 divs to have the same identifier, use a class instead (like I did in my example above with `language_wrapper`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this to the delete button:

```
position: relative;
top: -30px;
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/FZ2a7/)

Comment: Rather than hacking away with negative values. It would probably be better to use `position:relative` on the parent element, and then `position:absolute` on the child http://jsfiddle.net/6XdcY/7/.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
#language a.language {
    display: block;
    height: 83%;   // reduce the height from 100%
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

Or

Add two properties in .delete class, like this:

```
.delete
{
    // other properties 
    position: relative;
    top: -35px;
}
```